# Can I open a popup TEXT window from an image click?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I have looked and looked, but have had no luck doing the following:

I have a portfolio section of a blog I'm putting together and I want to have images that when clicked a popup window opens that contains text. I know there's lots of plugins to allow you to click on text and an image opens, but I want it the other way around.

I would like the popup to consist of white text on a red background, which would go with my theme. And if possible I would like to have a link in the text that when clicked would close the popup and go to that link in the main window (the links would be to posts in the blog).

I'm willing to pay for a commercial plugin if it's available. I have this site pretty well done, but can't show it to my client until I get this part of it worked out.

here's a link to the site so you have an idea of the page I'm looking to do this on:

http://bluegrassphotography.net/testwordpress/?cat=9&paged=2

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please consider marking an answer correct if the information provided was satisfactory in answering your question.

Answer (score 2):

Enter [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) - check out the examples below the images, specifally **Inline - modal window**.

If this seems like the ticket, it's a very straightforward process of [including it in your theme](http://fancybox.net/howto) and then either following the [examples](http://fancybox.net/blog) or [skimming the API](http://fancybox.net/api).

Let us know how you get on, or if you need a little help setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using some basic JS if you want to roll your own, see here for some examples.
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html

You could probably also use the thickbox script if you're looking for modal-style dialog..
http://wpengineer.com/415/use-javascript-libraries-in-and-of-wordpress/

**NOTE:** You don't have to load an image into that modal window, though that is it's typical use.

Lots of options, use whichever suits your needs most..

Personally i think the UI Dialog scripts looks interesting(would be overkill for a singular box though imho).
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog